# Rails partial with optional variable not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views

I'm not sure what's going on here but the following throws an error on render:

```
<%= render 'clients/clients_table', special: true %>
```

and in my partial I have:

```
<% if defined?(:special) %>
    <p><%= special %></p> <!-- line with error -->
<% else %>
    <p>No</p>
<% end -%>
```

This throw the error:

```
undefined local variable or method `special' for #<#<Class:0x007fa20fbb0310>:0x007fa20cb986a0>
```

When I try to display `local_assigns.has_key?(:special)` it also shows `false`.  Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I always recommend sending variables under the [`locals:`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables) key rather than directly. Maybe try this:

```
<%= render 'clients/clients_table', locals: {special: true} %>
```

Also in your partial this `defined?(:special)` is incorrect because it will always be truthy

```
defined?(:special)
#=> "expression"
```

Instead use `local_assigns` e.g.

```
<% if local_assigns[:special] %>
```

Answer (score 1):

`defined?(:special)` checks if the **symbol** `:special` is defined. It always is.

You want to check if the **variable** `special` is defined: `defined?(special)`